# Как тестировать void методы при помощи Mockito?

Tags: mockito

Есть сервлет который добавляет пользователей в базу используя инстанс модуля который за работу с базой отвечает. Необходимо протестировать этот сервлет при помощи `mock` объекта. Но как понять по какому сценарию на самом деле пошло выполнение кода?

Как мне сделать такой `mock` объект, что-бы сказать что если у него был вызван метод `addUser(User)` то из getUser() вернуть его же?

Что-то вроде:

```
//Объект работы с базой
ScriptExecutor executor = mock(ScriptExecutor.class);
//Как эту строчку при помощи мокито написать?
еслиУОбъектаExecutorБудетВызванМетодAddUserТоЕгоМетодGetUserВернетЭтогоЮзера
```

Код сервлета:

```
public class AddUserServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8");

        try {

            final boolean success = addUserInDatabase(req);

            if (success) req.setAttribute("serverAnswer", EDIT_SUCCESS.get());
            else req.setAttribute("serverAnswer", ERR_UNIQUE_L_P.get());

            req.getRequestDispatcher(ANSWER.get())
                    .forward(req, resp);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Addition user in database.
     *
     * @return true if addition success, else false.
     */
    private boolean addUserInDatabase(final HttpServletRequest req)
            throws SQLException {

        final User user = getUserFromRequest(req);
        return getDatabaseExecutor().addUserAndGetSuccess(user);
    }

    /**
     * Extracts user's data from HttpServletRequest.
     *
     * @return user from request.
     */
    private User getUserFromRequest(final HttpServletRequest req) {
        return new User(
                req.getParameter("name"),
                req.getParameter("login"),
                req.getParameter("password"),
                req.getParameter("email"),
                req.getParameter("role")
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get executor database requests.
     */
    private ScriptExecutor getDatabaseExecutor() throws SQLException {
        final DBJoint db = (DBJoint) getServletContext().getAttribute("db");
        return db.getDBScriptExecutor();
    }
}
```

Comment: можете добавить код сервлета?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman добавил